# HTACCESS file modified but still no GZIP compression

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel

EDITED - I ran speed tests on my site with google page speed insights and some anomalies emerged regarding text compression. I verified that on the site was not active the text compression (Content-Encoding not present in the Response Headers) and then I modified the root htaccess file like this:

```
# ORIGINAL CODE

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

        # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

        # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
        # BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
        # the above regex won't work. You can use the following
        # workaround to get the desired effect:
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # Don't compress images
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# CODE ADDED TO ACTIVATE COMPRESSION

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

I think the server is Apache, in google developer tools it just says:

```
server: - WordPress Hosting by https://www.vhosting-it.com
```

However after these changes the speed checker keeps giving me the same errors and I still don't see the Content-Encoding in the Response Headers.  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You have added not added the code completely to make it work.

Do add the below code at end of your .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN GZIP COMPRESSION
<IfModulemod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_onYes
mod_gzip_dechunkYes
mod_gzip_item_includefile.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_includehandler^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_includemime^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_includemime^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_excludemime^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_excluderspheader^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
# END GZIP COMPRESSION
```

Add the following line of codes if your website is hosted on a Nginx server.

```
gzipon;
gzip_comp_level2;
gzip_http_version1.0;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_min_length1100;
gzip_buffers168k;
gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
gzip_disable"MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";
gzip_varyon;
```

After adding the code you can go to webpagetest or anyother speed test site for confirmation. This will work 100% but, still in any case you will not able to achieve it, can comment below, would love to assist you.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your suggestions. I pasted the code you reported at the end of the htaccess file (root folder) but now the site is no longer reachable, it returns me 503 code. I modified the post with the original code of the file, is this due to the default settings?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in the .htaccess file.

`<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>`

Hope this will help.